# VBA - Locking Cells Only Working In Some Cells and Not Others

Tags: excel, vba

this project is certainly testing my limits in VBA.  I have yet another question.   In this workbook, I have a button called "Add Projects" that takes a different sheet "Project Templates" and uses it to create a new sheet called "Add Projects".  I'm trying to add some specific cell locking when this sheet is created.  The idea is that users can alter certain areas, but not ones that have formulas or are auto-populated by an entry in a different cell.

The problem is, when I add the code, certain ones lock appropriately, one particular cell does a popup asking for a password (when it should just be locked like the others), and some let you still edit them despite them being included in the locked code.

I've checked the cell format, and the box for locked is selected.  I've also gone to the Allow Users to Edit Ranges and removed everything from there (although those ranges weren't in there).  I've moved the order of the ranges around, thinking maybe they were somehow overwriting each other even though I have a distinct cell set as the end range.

```
Public Sub Open_AddProjectSheet()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
ActiveWorkbook.Unprotect Password:="Password"
Worksheets("ProjTemplate").Visible = True

If WorksheetExists("AddProject") = False Then
 GetTSResourceInfo
 GetTSProjectID
 ActiveWorkbook.Unprotect Password:="Password"
Worksheets("ProjTemplate").Copy After:=Worksheets("ProjTemplate")
ActiveSheet.Name = "AddProject"
 Worksheets("ProjTemplate").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
Sheets("AddProject").Activate
ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="Password"
ActiveSheet.Cells.Locked = False
ActiveSheet.Range("E5,C6,L2,L6").Locked = True
ActiveSheet.Range("E11:E190").Locked = True
ActiveSheet.Range("G11:H190").Locked = True
ActiveSheet.Range("K2:K6").Locked = True
ActiveSheet.Range("L11:R190").Locked = True
ActiveSheet.Range("L3:L5").Locked = False
ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="Password",UserInterFaceOnly:=True,Contents:=True
Else
answer = MsgBox("'AddProject' sheet already active. Would you like to pick up where you left?  WARNING: Selecting 'No' will close the existing sheet and open a new one, any progress will not be saved.", vbYesNo)

    If answer = 6 Then
        Worksheets("AddProject").Activate
        Else
            *Same code as above*
    End If

End If
Worksheets("ProjTemplate").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
ActiveWorkbook.Protect Password:="Password"
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 End Sub
```

When running this code, E5,C6,K2-K6,L2,L11-R190 are all locked correctly. L6 brings up a popup asking for a password to change this cell.  All other ranges, E11-E190, G11-H190 are editable even though they should be locked.

Any ideas I'm greatly appreciative of.  Thanks!

Comment: Should have added; even before adding the cell security, this macro started working slower than it used to.  No other macros in the workbook have appeared to slow down as much.

Comment: Note that `ActiveSheet.ProtectPassword:="Password"` is missing a space between `.Protect Password:="Password"`. • Also avoid using `ActiveSheet` which is not very reliable. Instead specify exactly which sheet you mean by its name.

Comment: Thank you, that was a typo in copying the code over, the code has the space for protect password correct in the workbook.  For the other, I switched ActiveSheet to the specific sheet, but unfortunately it did not change the cell locking issues.

Answer (score 0):

So, even though it didn't work before, we went back and tried to alter the Allow Users to Edit Ranges.  Wiped all of them out again and the cell locking started working.  I'm not going to question why it worked vs not working the last time it was tried, just glad it's working!   That being said, the speed being different is still an issue.